# HSQLDB Unexpected token: GETDATE

Tags: java, hibernate, hsqldb

JPA & Hibernate application uses HSQLDB for JUnit tests.

- HSQLDB 1.8.0
- Hibernate 3.2.4.sp1
- Java 7

While the tests worked fine against an Oracle database, getting the following error now that we are using MSSQL 2016:

`Unexpected token: GETDATE in statement [select ..... effective_date < GETDATE() AND ... ]`

So I understand that HSQL uses `SYSDATE`, `CURDATE`, or `NOW` instead of the MSSQL `GETDATE` function, and I've done the following:

Attempted to set `sql.syntax_mss` to true by URL and SQL statement:

```
public static final String HYPERSONIC_JDBC_URL = "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:aname;sql.syntax_mss=true";

entityManager.createNativeQuery("set database sql syntax MSS true").executeUpdate();
```

Register the function in the Dialect and/or create a function:

```
registerFunction("GETDATE", new NoArgSQLFunction("SYSDATE", new DateType()));

entityManager.createNativeQuery("CREATE FUNCTION GETDATE() RETURNS DATE RETURN CURDATE()").executeUpdate();
```

None of this seems to have any effect.

Live application is connected to MS SQL Server 2016 via mssql-jdbc-6.2.1.jre7 driver.

Comment: You need to use the up-to-date HSQLDB 2.4.x, not a version from 13 years ago.

Comment: @fredt Upgrading is always the first thought, this ran fine against Oracle 12c though. Most of the libraries are 11 years old and work just fine. (not saying it *shouldn't* be upgraded, but that is whole other issue)

Comment: The `sql.syntax_mss` on the database URL and `set database sql syntax mss true` do not work with older versions.

Comment: @fredt you should put those two comments into an answer. I'm going to attempt to upgrade and see what else breaks. If there are no other options, than that would be the answer. Odd that Oracle functions all work though.

Answer (score 0):

So while upgrading the libraries as @fredt mentioned in the comments is probably the best route, upgrading hsqldb.jar breaks dbunit.jar, upgrading that breaks.. etc.

Was able to remove the GETDATE occurrences and fix the sequence generation strings (`select next value for seq_name from seq_name` is the format it likes) and now we are back to a working state.

Upgrading these libraries can be put in the bucket with upgrading jBoss, Hiberate, jBPM and Quartz :)